# How to get rid from bad bind operator, the problems with if condition?

Tags: plsql

I need to prevent the captain and first officer if the if-condition is true

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER noPilot
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON flight
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
    captainS varchar2(5);
    firstOfficerS varchar2(5);

BEGIN

Select F.captainStaffID
into captainS
from Flight.F
where F.StaffID = captainS;

select F.firstOfficerStaffID
into firstOfficerS
from Flight F
where F.StaffID = firstOfficerS;

If(UPPER(:old.pilotYesNo = 'N')) THEN
    RETURN 'No pilot to launch'; 

elsif(:old.qualification = 'ATPL') THEN
    RETURN 'No qualifications';

    ENDIF;
END nopilot;
/



17/10    PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.PILOTYESNO'
20/7     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.QUALIFICATION'
24/5     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "NOPILOT" when expecting one of
     the following:
     if
```

the tables for the above is as follows;

FLIGHT(flightID, estDepartureDateTime, actDepartDateTime, actArriveDateTime, avgSpeed,avgHeight, estDuration, estFuel, haulType, captainStaffID, firstOfficerStaffID, routeID, aircraftID)

STAFF(staffID, name, address, email, phone, passportNum, pilotYesNo, prevHrsPilotExp,attendantYesNo, memberID)

Comment: I believe you need to change :old.pilotYesNo = 'N' to :old.pilotYesNo == 'N'  AND Select F.captainStaffID
into captainS
from Flight.F
where F.StaffID = captainS; to Select F.captainStaffID
into captainS
from Flight F
where F.StaffID = captainS;

Comment: @Satya the second part you have highlighted seems to be the same thing

Comment: By the way, PL/SQL syntax has no brackets around `if` conditions (it has a `then` keyword` instead). The compiler is politely ignoring the brackets in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that there are no `PILOTYESNO` or `QUALIFICATION` fields on the `FLIGHT` table. You might want to edit your question and include the definitions of the `FLIGHT` table so that people can understand it better.

Further, triggers do not return values, so the `RETURN` statements are invalid in a trigger. Perhaps you should raise an exception here.

Also, when this trigger executes you're probably going to get a `MUTATING TABLE` exception at run time because you're defining a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` ROW trigger in which you're selecting data in the body of the trigger from the same table (`FLIGHT`) that the trigger is defined on. This is not allowed in Oracle. Perhaps you should reference values in the `:NEW` pseudo-row.

A better solution would be to define a procedure (perhaps named `INSERT_OR_UPDATE_FLIGHT`) which performs all necessary checks, etc, prior to trying to do the appropriate INSERT or UPDATE. Putting business logic in triggers is s͟i̶m҉ply͞ Eͪ̂͛ͩ͂̽̈́V̩̼ͭ͊̐ͭ̀I̦͇̤͕̗̩̪͑Ĺ̨̩̱̘͇̰̲̀͌͆̄. :-)

Best of luck.

## EDIT

As I noted earlier, according to the table definitions added to the question there are no `PILOTYESNO` or `QUALIFICATION` fields on the `FLIGHT` table. `PILOTYESNO` is a field on the `STAFF` table, not on `FLIGHT`. There is no `QUALIFICATION` field on either the `FLIGHT` or `STAFF` tables, so I don't know what to recommend there. Are there other tables in play here which haven't been mentioned yet?

Regardless, I think you can get closer to what you want with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER FLIGHT_BIU
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON FLIGHT
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  strMAX_PILOTYESNO  STAFF.PILOTYESNO%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(UPPER(PILOTYESNO))
    INTO strMAX_PILOTYESNO  
    FROM STAFF
    WHERE STAFFID IN (:NEW.CAPTAINSTAFFID, :NEW.FIRSTOFFICERSTAFFID);

  IF strMAX_PILOTYESNO  = 'N' THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'No pilot assigned to the flight');
  END IF;

  -- Add code here to handle QUALIFICATION, wherever that may be found
END FLIGHT_BIU;
/
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the beautifully crafted explanation @Bob

Comment: @bob if you can find me the place that I should make amendments! I have no idea either